# How do I allow a iframe with a content security policy (CSP)

Tags: security, iframe, content-security-policy

I am setting up a content security policy (CSP)for my website. I have been using it for a few websites for the last weeks without any issue. External scripts and various other things I have successfully integrated.

Today though I wanted to integrate a third part calendar booking system (Calendly). They use an iframe for the popup and for the life of me I can not get it accepted on the security policy.

I keep getting this error
"refused to frame 'url-to-calendly' because it violates the following content security policy directive: "frame-src" ...

I have tired adding this to the frame-src component
`frame-src https://assets.calendly.com;`
`frame-src 'self' https://assets.calendly.com;`
`frame-src 'self' https://assets.calendly.com 'unsafe-inline';`
`frame-src https://assets.calendly.com 'nonce-lots-of-digits';`
`frame-src 'self' https://assets.calendly.com 'nonce-lots-of-digits';`

I did the same under the `child-src` directive as well. Since frame-src is no longer used in version two. Again this did not work either. Here is my full CSP. Any help here would be greatly appreciated - thank you. Ps. I was using chrome dev tools. It appeared to neither work in Safari either.

```
Content-Security-Policy: 
script-src 'nonce-4dfb7738f82d40efc1b73a80491d6dd0bb839173' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; 
default-src 'nonce-77184b203c574dfd8ecc7fac417bf078242d4657'; 
img-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net; 
style-src 'self' https://assets.calendly.com; 
font-src 'self'; 
connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net; 
base-uri 'none'; 
child-src https://assets.calendly.com; 
frame-src https://assets.calendly.com;
```

Comment: The cause isn't in your CSP policy, so you can't fix it in your CSP policy. The cause is that the `https://assets.calendly.com` site itself is being served with a header that tells browsers to not allow other sites to frame it. So your browser is respecting that header and not allowing your site to frame that one. And there is no way you can override that. There's no way your site can frame that one.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thank you so much for getting back to me. How did you find out it was calendly causing the issue? I am so relieaved it wasn’t the CSP. I was losing my mind because I could not see what I was doing wrong. Do you know of any steps to get around this problem - other than contacting calendly directly (which I have already done)? Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: @sideshowbarker How did you know it was calendly causing the issue and not davidlower8's implementation of his iframe / CSP?  Thank you.

Comment: @mike_butak If you use the Network pane in browser devtools, or curl or Postman or whatever, and check the response headers for the response from https://assets.calendly.com, it shows that the response includes the `x-frame-options: deny`, which means that `https://assets.calendly.com` is saying *“Don’t allow other sites to put me in a frame”*. So browsers obey that and refuse to allow the site in the question to show https://assets.calendly.com in a frame.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thank you! Your response really helps. I see 209 requests in the network tab, none of which include the resource requested in the iframe (which in my case is not calendly, but an internal site I've developed in our company). It might be interesting to note that my code works in the old version of the client, and my iframed app loads just fine. The updated version of the client is where I'm having trouble. I don't control the client code apart from the form designer in which I'm injecting this iframe via javascript.

Answer (score 10):

To make Calendly work on your website you need to add following CSP rules:

```
frame-src https://calendly.com;
script-src https://assets.calendly.com;
style-src 'unsafe-inline';
```

Comment: Where do i have to add these?

Comment: @KumailR It depends on what you're using, but the service you use to serve your website is where you would specify the CSP header. e.g. nginx, express, etc.

Answer (score 8):

So actually the answer turned out to be very simple. I contacted calendly directly and the simple solution was to change the url I added. `https://calendly.com` was enough to do the trick.

So the url you gave @andrii was correct - thank you. However using ‘unsafe-inline’ is not advisable. Using that on any of the sources makes your CSP almost pointless having.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' ; 
        img-src      'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
                      https://www.google.com/;
        style-src     'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
                      https://fonts.googleapis.com ;
        script-src    'self' 'unsafe-inline'  
                       https://www.google-analytics.com
                       https://www.torrentpower.com; 
        connect-src    'self' 
                       https://google.com/
                       https://www.google-analytics.com;
        child-src 'self' https://www.google.com/;
                         object-src 'self';">
```

Comment: what are som pros of this? how does unsafe-inline work?